# How do I make the html select options work in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am having trouble getting an HTML Select Options to work the way I think it should work in Meteor.

Here is an example of how it would work with buttons for a collection called Countries.

Template

```
{{#each get_countries}}
  <button class="btn btnCountryTest">{{iso3}} - {{name}} </button><br />
{{/each}}
```

Client event handler

```
'click .btnCountryTest': function(event){
   console.log('clicked .btnCountryTest this._id: ' + this._id);
}
```

Produces the correct output such as.

```
clicked .btnCountryTest this._id: 39cd432c-66fa-48de-908b-93a874323e2e
```

Now, what I want to be able to do is trigger other on page activity when an item is selected from an HTML Select Options drop down.  I know I could put the ID in the options value and then use Jquery etc...  I thought it would "just work" with Meteor but I can't figure out how to do it.

Here is what I am trying and it is not working.

Template

```
<select class="input-xlarge country" id="country" name="country">
  {{#each get_countries}}
    <option value="{{iso3}}">{{name}}</option>
  {{/each}}
</select>
```

Handler

```
'click #country': function (event) { 
  console.log('Template.users_insert.events click .country this._id: ' + this._id);
 }
```

Which produces

```
Template.users_insert.events click .country this._id: undefined
```

Clearly not what I had expected.  Any ideas anyone before I resort to Jquery form processing?

Thanks
Steeve

Answer (score 5):

In Meteor, `each` helper calls `Meteor.ui.listChunk` (please take a look at packages/templating/deftemplate.js), which treats the current variable as `this` context.

In other words, it's the global context in `click #country`, and you can only access `this._id` under `each` block, like in the `click #country option` event.

I think you can put the data in HTML data attribute, and access it using jQuery. Just like this -

Template

```
<select class="input-xlarge country" id="country" name="country">
  {{#each get_countries}}
    <option value="{{iso3}}" data-id={{_id}}>{{name}}</option>
  {{/each}}
</select>
```

Handle

```
'click #country': function (event) { 
  console.log('Template.users_insert.events click .country this._id: ' + $(event.currentTarget).find(':selected').data("id"));
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to get to the data context, you need to give your event handler access to the `template` argument, and use it's `data` object. That is the top level data context.

```js
'click #country': function (event, template) { 
    console.log('Template.users_insert.events click .country _id: ' + template.data._id);
}
```

should work. Here's the best documentation I can find on this: http://docs.meteor.com/#template_data

Answer (score 2):

@StevenCannon, I had a similar issue and found a solution here - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/meteor/meteor_forms.htm. @DenisBrat is correct, listen for the change event instead of the click event.

Here's the solution modified for you:

```
'change select'(event) {
    // Prevent default browser form submit
    event.preventDefault();

    var selectedCountry = event.target.value;

    console.log('Template.users_insert.events change select iso3: ' + selectedCountry);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're listening for the 'click' event of the select. You'd really like to subscribe to the 'change' event. 'Click' occurs when you click on a html element. On the other hand, 'change' event gets triggered after you select a value from the list.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can also take a look at 'packages/liveui/liveui.js'. There is a `findEventData` function, which give the callback `this` object.